# Error when global variable in Orchestrator 2012 is encrypted

Tags: powershell, orchestration

I'm trying to use some credentials so I can connect to MicrosoftTeams using powershell with orchestrator. I need a username and its password. The password is stored as a global variable, encrypted. When I try to connect to MicrosoftTeams it says that the password is incorrent. However, when I put the password hard coded there is no problem, and I can connect to Microsoft Teams.
Here is my code:

```
   $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString '{password}' -AsPlainText -Force 
   $admin ="admin@admin.com"
   $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentList $admin, $password

  connect-MicrosoftTeams -credential $cred
```

Has someone had the same issue?

Comment: `-argumentList $admin, $password` --> `-argumentList $admin, $Pass`. (use the SecureString password)

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was because I was using a PowerShell Script activity. It turns out that this activity can't read encrypted variables. To solve this problem I just enctypted the password and stored it in my C: drive, then I just got the content from that file. If someone wants the code for that, please ask.